# How does one create iterateable lists of objects in C++?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, class, struct

I'm starting out C++ coming from Python, so I'm pretty much just scrolling through the basics. Problem occurs when I try to make an array with objects in it. In Python I would have a class Car with the attributes `color` and `year`:

```
myCars = [Car("Red", 1986), Car("Black", 2007), Car("Blue", 1993)]
# and then going through the cars:
for car in myCars:
print("The car has the color " + car.color + " and is " + (2014 - car.year) + " years old.")
```

Trying to do something similar in C++:

```
struct Car {
    string color;
    int year;
};

int cars[3] = {Car cars[0], Car cars[1], Car cars[2]}
//EDIT: I wrote bilar but I meant cars.
```

but it is indeed uninteresting to iterate over these cars, as for one, this doesn't work, and secondly, they doesn't have any attributes. I just don't understand, I think maybe I've missed something important and got it all wrong, but then, I reckon I just gotta have this explained clean and nice.

Comment: When you use `int bilar[3]` you are creating an array of integers. You need to use `Car bilar[3]`.

Comment: @IanAuld That sounds logical, I was wondering about the types... but then, how does one assign any values to `car[x]`? Do I have to write `car[2].color = "Red"` and so on on a line for every assignment?

Comment: You can create constructors in C++ just like in Python so you can do `Car my_car = Car('Red', '2007');`. I'm a Python guy myself and my C++ is a little rusty so I don't remember exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Try this (C++11) - looks almost like Python:

```
std::vector<Car> cars = {{"Red", 1986}, {"Black", 2007}, {"Blue", 1993}};
for (const Car& car : cars) {
    std::cout << "The car has the color " << car.color << " and is " 
        << (2014 - car.year) << " years old." << std::endl;
}
```

C++ constructs involved:

- [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)
- [range `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: What does `const` mean and does this mean I'm using a vector and what does that mean, exactly? Also, I assume the `:` kind of means `in`?

Comment: The `const` means that the `car` should be immutable. And a `std::vector` should be basically indistinguishable from a Python list.

Answer (score 1):

The standard containers are iterable, if you can't use C++11 syntax (as the one suggested by Anton Savin) for some reason, you can use the more verbose older style:

```
for (std::vector<Car>::const_iterator it=cars.begin(); it != cars.end(); ++it) {
    const Car & car = *it;
    std::cout << "The car has the color " << car.color << " and is " 
        << (2014 - car.year) << " years old." << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It`s not necessary to use vector. You may create an array instead of std::vector.

```
Car cars[] = {{"Red", 1986}, {"Black", 2007}, {"Blue", 1993}};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "The car has the color " << cars[i].color << " and is " 
        << (2014 - cars[i].year) << " years old." << std::endl;
}
```

Hope it`s compiles...